# Justification of termwise integration

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

Please explain how the final line of the following proof implies the result of the corollary?
(Note that the main middle section of the proof is for a preceding theorem.)[image]

Comment: Since $f_k$ is a finite sum, you have $$\int_a^b f_k(x)\,dx = \int_a^b \sum_{i=1}^k g_i(x)\,dx = \sum_{i=1}^k \int_a^b g_i(x)\,dx.$$ Does that clear it up?

Comment: @DanielFischer YES! Would you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $f_k$ are finite sums of the $g_i$, hence you have

$$\int_a^b f_k(x)\,dx = \int_a^b \sum_{i=1}^k g_i(x)\,dx = \sum_{i=1}^k \int_a^b g_i(x)\,dx$$

by the linearity of the integral. Since the series $g_i$ is supposed to converge uniformly, the sequence of the $f_k$ satisfies the premise of the theorem that limit and integral can be interchanged. Taking the limit inside the integral gives

$$\int_a^b \sum_{i=1}^\infty g_i(x)\,dx$$

and taking the limit of the sum of the integrals gives

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_a^b g_i(x)\,dx.$$